# Carry left-overs from 'join" on to the next day's job in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a job that runs on a daily basis. The purpose of this job is to correlate HTTP requests with their corresponding HTTP replies. This can be achieved because all HTTP requests & HTTP replies have a GUID that uniquely binds them.

So the job deals with two DataFrames: one containing the requests, and one containing the replies. So to correlate the requests with their replies, I am obviously doing an inner join based on that GUID.

The problem that I am running into is that a request that was captured on day X at 23:59:59 might see its reply captured on day X+1 at 00:00:01 (or vice-versa) which means that they will never get correlated together, neither on day X nor on day X+1.

Here is example code that illustrates what I mean:

```
val day1_requests = """[ { "id1": "guid_a", "val" : 1 }, { "id1": "guid_b", "val" : 3 }, { "id1": "guid_c", "val" : 5 }, { "id1": "guid_d", "val" : 7 } ]"""
val day1_replies  = """[ { "id2": "guid_a", "val" : 2 }, { "id2": "guid_b", "val" : 4 }, { "id2": "guid_c", "val" : 6 },                                { "id2": "guid_e", "val" : 10 } ]"""

val day2_requests = """[                                 { "id1": "guid_e", "val" :  9 }, { "id1": "guid_f", "val" : 11 }, { "id1": "guid_g", "val" : 13 }, { "id1": "guid_h", "val" : 15 } ]"""
val day2_replies  = """[ { "id2": "guid_d", "val" : 8 },                                  { "id2": "guid_f", "val" : 12 }, { "id2": "guid_g", "val" : 14 }, { "id2": "guid_h", "val" : 16 } ]"""

val day1_df_requests = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(day1_requests :: Nil))
val day1_df_replies  = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(day1_replies  :: Nil))

val day2_df_requests = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(day2_requests :: Nil))
val day2_df_replies  = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(day2_replies  :: Nil))

day1_df_requests.show()
day1_df_replies.show()
day2_df_requests.show()
day2_df_replies.show()

day1_df_requests.join(day1_df_replies, day1_df_requests("id1") === day1_df_replies("id2")).show()
// guid_d from request stream is left over, as well as guid_e from reply stream.
//
// The following 'join' is done on the following day.
// I would like to carry 'guid_d' into day2_df_requests and 'guid_e' into day2_df_replies).
day2_df_requests.join(day2_df_replies, day2_df_requests("id1") === day2_df_replies("id2")).show()
```

I can see 2 solutions.

**Solution#1 - custom carry over**

In this solution, on day X, I would do a "full_outer" join instead of an inner-join, and I would persist into some storage the results that are missing one side or the other. On the next day X+1, I would load this extra data along with my "regular data" when doing my join.

> An additional implementation detail is that my custom carry over would have to discard "old carry overs" otherwise it could pile up, i.e. it is possible that a HTTP request or HTTP reply from 10 days ago never sees its counterpart (maybe the app crashed for instance thus a HTTP request was emitted but not a reply).

**Solution#2 - guid folding**

In this solution, I would make the assumption that my requests and replies are within a certain amount of time of one another (e.g. 5 minutes). Thus on day X+1, I would also load the last 5 minutes of data from day X and include that as part of my join. This way, I don't need to use extra storage like in solution#1. However, the disadvantage is that this solution requires that the target storage can deal with duplicate entries (for instance, if the target storage is a SQL table, the PK would have to be this GUID and do an upsert instead of an insert).

---

**Question**

So my question is whether Spark provides functionality to automatically deal with a situation like that, thus not requiring any of my two solutions and by the same fact making things easier and more elegant?

---

**Bonus question**

Let's assume that I need to do the same type of correlation but with a stream of data (i.e. instead of a daily batch job that runs on a static set of data, I use Spark Streaming and data is processed on live streams of requests & replies).

In this scenario, a "full_outer" join is obviously inappropriate (https://dzone.com/articles/spark-structured-streaming-joins) and actually unnecessary since Spark Streaming takes care of that for us by having a sliding window for doing the join.

However, I am curious to know what happens if the job is stopped (or if it crashes) then resumed. Similarly to the batch mode example that I gave above, what if the job was interrupted after a request was consumed (and acknowledged) from stream/queue but **before** its related reply did? Does Spark Streaming keeps a state of its sliding window hence resuming the job will be able to correlate as if the stream was never interrupted?

P.S. backing up your answer with hyperlinks to reputable docs (like Apache's own) would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use structured streaming with watermarks?

Comment: I think you might be right. I did not realize that Spark Streaming could use static files as its input source. I assume this is the exact doc that you were referring to:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And you can take a look at `Trigger.Once`